# Understanding: conversion from long_ptr to bool possible loss of data

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, casting

I am fresh off from learning C++  and to learn winapi, I am doing the Forgers Win32 API tutorial.

Here is my code:

```
//MyControl.h
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL BrushExists(HBRUSH hBrush);
-------------------------------------------------------
//MyControl.cpp
#include "MyControl.h"

HBRUSH g_hbrBackground = NULL;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    return (int)DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgProc);
}

BOOL BrushExists(HBRUSH hBrush) // I added this to better understand what is happening
{
    if (hBrush)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        g_hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
//... Other code skipped copy pasting ...
    }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
//... Other code skipped copy pasting ...
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLORDLG:
        return (LONG_PTR)g_hbrBackground; // Where casting happens
//      return BrushExists(g_hbrBackground); // Tried this to understand things
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        SetBkMode(hdcStatic, TRANSPARENT);
        return (LONG_PTR)g_hbrBackground; // Where casting happens
//      return BrushExists(g_hbrBackground); // Tried this to understand things
    }
        break;
//... Other code skipped copy pasting ...
}
```

The code compiles and gives the warning: `C4244: 'return': conversion from 'LONG_PTR' to 'BOOL', possible loss of data`

The casting works and the dialog box is colored right as expected:
[Black colored dialog.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Cim.png)

My question: What happens in the background when HBRUSH is returned as a LONG_PTR from a function (DLGPROC) that returns BOOL? My assumption from reading C++ was that if the LONG_PTR is non-zero then the BOOL returned is TRUE and if LONG_PTR is zero then the BOOL returned is FALSE. To check this I created the function `BOOL BrushExists(HBRUSH hBrush);// See code`. Using this function to check for the HBRUSH and return TRUE, compiles without warnings and runs without error. But the coloring of the Dialog box does not happen:
[Black color missing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMPf9.png)

So my assumption is wrong. The `LONG_PTR` seems to be evaluated by the win32 API as a number instead of as a `BOOL`. Can someone explain to me how this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it's `BOOL` and not `bool`. With the Windows SDK, `BOOL` is a typedef for `int`, which can store a 32-bit value - it's not a simple boolean that can only store `true` or `false`.

This is a kludge in the API basically. In 32 bit Windows, a brush handle fits in a 32 bit value, and even though it's ugly and potentially confusing, it's "safe" to return a brush handle cast as a `BOOL` (and you had to cast it, since that's what `DialogProc` was defined as returning).

Once Windows gained 64 bit support this situation obviously wasn't acceptable - in this example, brush handles (which are pointers) are 64 bits in size - casting them to a 32-bit type isn't safe.

Therefore, the definition of `DialogProc` was changed to return `INT_PTR` rather than `BOOL`. This is typedefed to 32-bits in x86 and 64-bits in x64. The example code you've used obviously pre-dates this change, but all new code should use the correct definition of `DialogProc` as returning `INT_PTR`.

Comment: *"This is a kludge in the API basically."* - Not a kludge, but a necessity. The Windows API predates the `bool` data type.

Comment: Thanks guys. That explained things and resolved my confusion.

Comment: Still a kludge. Regardless of how BOOL is typedefed (i.e., how many actual bits its representation has), it still *semantically* represents a boolean value. Returning anything other than true/false breaks that semantic contract. The dialog procedure should have returned a INT or DWORD or equivalent from the beginning.

Comment: Do note, @sivakumar, that it gets even more confusing than this. Dialog procedures are different from window procedures. Generally, if you want to return a value from a dialog procedure, you need to call SetWindowLongPtr with the DWLP_MSGRESULT flag, and then simply return TRUE from the dialog procedure. The brush handle returned in response to WM_CTLCOLOR* is one of the few exceptions to this general rule, in that you actually cast and return it directly from the dialog procedure, just like you would if you were writing a window procedure.

Answer (score 0):

- `BOOL` is nothing but `int` typedef'd.
- `LONG_PTR` may be either `long int` or `__int64` - depending on platform chosen.

From header:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
typedef __int64             LONG_PTR;
#else
typedef long           LONG_PTR;
#endif
```

You seem to be building the project as x64 compiler, and hence `BOOL` to `LONG_PTR` (essentially `int` to `int64`) is giving you warning.

Note that `int` and `long` are essentially same on Visual C++/Windows.

Comment: Thanks Ajay for the explanation.